# Split text into phrases of a person and an operator

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, speech-to-text

I have about 5,000 texts without punctuation marks.
Each text is a conversation between an operator and a person.
For example: "Hello hello how can I help you how can I find out how much money I have in my account"

How can one separate phrases between a person and an operator using machine learning methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the task you're looking for is called "Punctuation restoration" or "Punctuation prediction". An example of this is described in this [paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W17-2319.pdf), or this other [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.00543).
Unfortunately I am not aware of available per-trained model that you might apply to your dataset. Honestly I think that it is unlikely that something trained specifically for costumer service calls exists, unless you want to annotate your own dataset and train a model out of it.